# When method in Extension method. FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

in the code below `x` is of type `string?` which is expected, but if I change `Must` to `When` then `x` is of type `T`

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string?> Example<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string?> rule, int maximumLength = 100)
        {
            return rule
                .Must(x => x?.Length > 0);
        }
```

I can not figure why this is happening. On simple rules it works, `x` is of type `string?`, but in extension method it becomes `T`, while methods that behave the same(I guess) work as expected

```
RuleFor(x => x.Line)
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(x => x.Line?.Length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that is should be done like this

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string?> Example<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string?> rule, int maximumLength = 100, Func<T, string?> str)
        {
            return rule
                .When(x => str(x).Length > 0);
        }
```